# WebChat using WebSocket is not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, cross-browser, webrtc

I am trying to build a web chat application. Started the development following this [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/webrtc/webrtc_text_demo.htm) as a baseline. It is working perfectly in windows chrome browser. That is Message is passed on between different chrome browsers.

But when i try to test the chat application with Safari browser it is not working. I narrow down the problem with simple example.

Server code: (ref from https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws)

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
 
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });
 
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });
 
  ws.send('something');
});
```

Client Code:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

When we are trying to get the signalling server (from the above Javascript line), we are getting the error.

```
Unexpected response code: 400
```

Please share your thoughts!

Comment: According to this [issue](https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/13), websockets are not supported for pre 6 versions (in the event you are testing on those versions). I also tested using `ws` package on the latest safari and it works fine

Comment: Thanks for your comment @codemax. Is this issue related to ios? Because while testing in iMac + Chrome we are facing same issue.

Comment: Yes, iMac + Chrome could face this issue if websockets is not supported. You may want to refer to [this](https://caniuse.com/websockets).